# Why so many repetitions in the Torah in relation to Moses and G'd?

Tags: hebrew, exodus

Another intriguing question caught my attention today and it is something that is repeated a lot in the **Torah** - who is G'd? An example of this can be found in **Exodus 6:10**:

> ## וַיְדַבֵּ֥ר יְהֹוָ֖ה אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֥ה לֵּאמֹֽר׃

In English it reads:

> יהוה spoke to Moses, saying,

I would like to know why this expression is repeated and what the difference is when using וַיְדַבֵּ֥ר and לֵּאמֹֽר ? Why to use them together?

Comment: I don't understand why _repetition_ could be questioned in a relationship between God and Moses when Moses' lifetime task (of his latter forty years) was to communicate what God spoke to his people, Israel. Would we not _expect_ a great deal of repetition of the phrase ?

Comment: I also do not understand the question.

Comment: @NigelJ "*Would we not expect a great deal of repetition of the phrase ?*" The OP intends to make sense of the --at least apparent-- redundancy in the combination of יְדַבֵּ֥ר and אמֹֽר . The question is more about literary style & Hebrew language than about a trivial implication from two entities having verbal communications. I see nothing wrong with the question. If I were knowledgeable enough about Hebrew, I would definitely address this question.

Comment: דבֵּר, like English "speak" cannot take a quotation as a direct argument. If you want to follow it with a quotation in English, you have to say something like _And the lord spoke these words: "..."_, with an element of redundancy (between "speak" and "words"). In Biblical Hebrew there is a similar redundancy between  דבֵּר and .אמר

Answer (score -1):

With angelic mediation, the פֶּה אֶל־פֶּה "mouth-to-mouth" discussions of YHVH to Moshe (Numbers 12:8) is synonymous in the phrase : " וַיְדַבֵּר יְהֹוָה אֶל־משֶׁ֥ה לֵּאמֹֽר " in [Exodus 6:10]. During his moments of Inspiration, Moshe always hears the מַלְאַ֨ךְ Malak 'Angel' of YHVH speaking - based on [Exodus 33:20]. | YHVH sends a malak (messenger) to Moshe, saying.

Comment: Can you explain more your reasoning?